# Expandable list view search filter

Tags: android, listview, searchview

I have tried to make `expandableListView` with a search filter. It's successful, however when I search it works, but when I click what I search, it's back to the first activity.
Here's the full `MainActivity` :

```
package com.example.tesskian;

import java.util.ArrayList;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
 SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener{

 private SearchView search;
 private mylistadapter listAdapter;
 private ExpandableListView myList;
 private ArrayList<continent> continentList = new ArrayList<continent>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
  search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
  search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
  search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
  search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
  search.setOnCloseListener(this);

  //display the list
  displayList();
  //expand all Groups
  expandAll();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //method to expand all groups
 private void expandAll() {
  int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
   myList.expandGroup(i);
  }
 }

 //method to expand all groups
 private void displayList() {

  //display the list
  loadSomeData();

  //get reference to the ExpandableListView
  myList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
  //create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
  listAdapter = new mylistadapter(MainActivity.this, continentList);
  //attach the adapter to the list
  myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);



 myList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (id = country("Introduction")) {
                if (childPosition == 0){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cont.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), con1.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), schema.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }


                if (childPosition == 3) {
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ajax.class);
             startActivity(i);
                }

                if (childPosition == 4) {
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), examples.class);
             startActivity(i);
                }
            }
                if (groupPosition == 1) {
                if (childPosition == 0) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), overview.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 1) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), arrai.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 2) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), bool.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 3) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), object.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 4) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), number.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 5) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), string.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 6) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tru.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 7) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), fals.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }

                if (childPosition == 8) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nulll.class);
                    startActivity(j);
                }


            }

        return false;
        }
    });
}


 private void loadSomeData() {

  ArrayList<country> countryList = new ArrayList<country>();
  country country = new country("Introduction");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Data Types");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Schema");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Use In Ajax");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Examples");
  countryList.add(country);

  continent continent = new continent("Basics",countryList);
  continentList.add(continent);

  countryList = new ArrayList<country>();
  country = new country("Overview");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Array");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Boolean");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Object");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Number");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("String");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("False");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("True");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new country("Null");
  countryList.add(country);

  continent = new continent("Data Types",countryList);
  continentList.add(continent);

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onClose() {
  listAdapter.filterData("");
  expandAll();
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
  listAdapter.filterData(query);
  expandAll();
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
  listAdapter.filterData(query);
  expandAll();
  return false;
 }
}
```

I want to make when I search "Examples" it's go to "examples.class".
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Download the source code from here ([Expandablelistview With Searchview In Android](http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.in/2018/02/expandablelistview-with-searchview-in.html))

You just need to notify the adapter on edittext change.

```
 et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                if (et_search.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(lv_country, getApplicationContext());
                    ev_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);

                    for (int i = 0; i < customAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                        ev_list.expandGroup(i);
                    }
                } else {

                    List> lv_search = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < lv_country.size(); i++) {
                        List> lv_searchstate = new ArrayList<>();

                        List> lv_state = (List>) lv_country.get(i).get("State");
                        for (int j = 0; j < lv_state.size(); j++) {
                            if (lv_state.get(j).get("Name").toString().toLowerCase().contains(et_search.getText().toString())) {
                                lv_searchstate.add(lv_state.get(j));
                            }
                        }

                        if (lv_searchstate.size() != 0) {
                            HashMap hashMap_search = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap_search.put("Name", lv_country.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                            hashMap_search.put("State", lv_searchstate);

                            lv_search.add(hashMap_search);
                        }
                    }


                    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(lv_search, getApplicationContext());
                    ev_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);

                    for (int i = 0; i < customAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                        ev_list.expandGroup(i);
                    }


                }

            }
        });
```

Thanks!